# Swapping words in method for Word Chain

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of words that all differ by one letter. I'm trying to make a word chain so that if the user enters one word, then the next word will differ by one character at random from that and then the next word will differ by one character of the last character.

Ex: test to nest to newt to nett to yett to yeti.

So I created the amount of words that differ by one letter to test.  I created a swap method:

```
public static void swap( String[] str, int pos1, int pos2){
int temp = arr[pos1];
arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
arr[pos2] = temp;
```

}

My professor recommended to swap the word to the last position in the list so that way you don't use it again, and then you look for a similar character position in the list that differs by one letter and then when you find that word, you keep swapping it to the end until you have no words left, or no similar positions left.

So my question is am I on the right track with swapping my words?

Comment: Do you have a dictionary with all possible words?

Comment: Yes I do!! And I created a method to find all words that differ by one character in this dictionary by simply entering a word. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I put this into a partial array list like I'm suppose to, and that why it's making swapping these indices very frustrating. I can post more of my code if it'd be of any help?

Comment: Honestly StackOverflow frowns upon people asking for homework help. You should ask a specific question about a part of your algorithm rather than asking for SO to solve it for you. I'll give you a hint though: you can take in the initial word, then use the dictionary to find the next word that differs by one character. Do this repetitively and you can build a list of 'like' words.

Answer (score 0):

If your only question is `am I on the right track with swapping my words?`, then yes, you are doing so correctly.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?